# Why me and my friend are getting different technology schematic view for same VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl, lookup-tables, xilinx-ise

We are implementing a 4-bit Multiplier using Full adder.

This is my first time using Xilinx in addition I also don't understand much about Look-up Table.

[My Technology Schematic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHNKI.jpg)

[My friend's Technology Schematic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQzuC.jpg)

Why am I getting a different Technology Schematic view? What is the difference between LUT2 and LUT4?

Comment: [Here is VHDL code](http://pasteonline.org/e3rSydqKc/). In addition both of us are using Xilinx ISE 9.2i.

Comment: Why is one called MULTIPLIER_MM_M and the other one multi?

Comment: Are the two of you compiling for different target devices, perhaps?  Different FPGA chips have different internal structures, the output will necessarily reflect these differences.

Comment: As @jasonharper pointed out, it looks as though these are for different devices. One solely uses 2 input LUTs, the other uses a combination of 2/3/4 input lookups

Comment: @jasonharper So we can have same RTL view for different target devices? As my friend's and my RTL view is same but only different in Schematic view.

Comment: If you're compiling the same RTL view for different FPGA families, it makes sense you'll see different schematic views, as different FPGA families offer different basic blocks.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

LUT2 is a lookup table with 2 input, LUT4 is a lookup table with 4 input.
You are getting different results most likely because you are using different settings or synthesis strategies. Typical the setting or synthesis strategies are used to trade-off between area usage and timing, therefore you can have different results. In any case, AFAIK you can not have a reproducible build for the synthesis PR process.

I hope this can help.
Bye.